SQL date window reset after
I am looking at a series of session dates of a user, and I am trying to “collapse” the event counts in a way that any event occurring in a 7 day time window is only counted once, starting from the first event and then again after the initial period of 7 days is over, and a new event (and a 7 day window) starts again.
I am trying to figure out a logic, where the count “breaks” and resets the window. Thank you!
WITH data1 AS (
    SELECT 'bob' AS user, DATE('2024-04-08') AS session_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bob', DATE('2024-04-11')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bob', DATE('2024-04-12')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bob', DATE('2024-04-17')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bob', DATE('2024-04-18')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bob', DATE('2024-04-22')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bob', DATE('2024-04-23')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bob', DATE('2024-04-25')
    
)

SELECT
    *,
    DATE_ADD(session_date, INTERVAL 7 day) AS session_date_end,
    COUNT(session_date) OVER (PARTITION BY user
                ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(session_date)
                RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 6 FOLLOWING) 
            AS next_7_days
FROM data1

input

desired output

Additional edit:
For example, if a user logs in on the 1st, 10th and 16th the windows should be 1st to 7th and 10th to 16th to accommodate varying user activity.

Lots of answers to this. You have to do it recursively/iteratively. I don't think BQ has special features for this problem to change that.

Thanks @shawnt00. Any suggestions you could link?

Maybe a decent start. I realize this is a different platform. https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/83841/38471

A [mre] should include the results you want for the give example data.

If a user logs in on the 1st, 10th and 16th are the windows meant to be 1st to 7th and 8th to 14th and 15th to 21st? Or should they be 1st to 7th and 10th to 16th?

@MatBailie, the latter, the window should not be a fixed time interval, but adjust to the data available 1st to 7th and 10th to 16th in your example.

Then please add that to your question's example data, and include the desired results.

WITH data1 AS (
    SELECT 'bob' AS user, DATE('2024-04-08') AS session_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bob', DATE('2024-04-11')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bob', DATE('2024-04-12')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bob', DATE('2024-04-17')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bob', DATE('2024-04-18')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bob', DATE('2024-04-22')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bob', DATE('2024-04-23')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bob', DATE('2024-04-25')
),

Lookup the preceding session date...
  look_behind AS
(
  SELECT
    data.*,
    LAG(session_date) OVER (
      PARTITION BY user
          ORDER BY session_date
    )
      AS previous_session_date
  FROM
    data1
),

Get the most recent session date which is more than 7 days after its preceding session's date.
(CASE expression ensures the first date is considered to be 7 days after, even though there is no preceding session date.)
  partitioned AS
(
  SELECT
    look_behind.*,
    LAST_VALUE(
      CASE WHEN session_date <= DATE_ADD(previous_session_date, INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN NULL ELSE session_date END
      IGNORE NULLS
    ) OVER (
      PARTITION BY user
          ORDER BY session_date
    )
      AS base_session_date
  FROM
    look_behind
)

Use dense rank to calculate the session id.
SELECT
  partitioned.*,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (
    PARTITION BY user
        ORDER BY base_session_date,
                 DIV(DATE_DIFF(session_date, base_session_date, DAY), 7)
  )
    AS user_session_id
FROM
  partitioned
ORDER BY
  user, session_date


Following query works only with window functions and CTE. If an user logs in at least once a week starting from a date X, we split all login events in blocks of 7 days from that date X. Lets say an user logs in every day starting on a Monday for one month. Then the user does not visit for two days and logs on a Wednesday again and comes back daily. Since the break is less than a week, we still look for the login events on a 7 day scale starting on Monday. Because the break was too short, the date interval was not changed and thus for these day less activy is measured.
WITH data1 AS (
    SELECT 'bob' AS user, DATE('2024-04-08') AS session_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bob', DATE('2024-04-11')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bob', DATE('2024-04-12')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bob', DATE('2024-04-17')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bob', DATE('2024-04-18')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bob', DATE('2024-04-22')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bob', DATE('2024-04-23')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bob', DATE('2024-04-25')
     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bob', DATE('2024-01-25')
      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bob', DATE('2024-01-29')
),

tbl1 as ( -- check if the last 7 days entries happend. 
  SELECT *, count(1) over win1 as temp1
  from data1
  window win1 as (partition by  user  ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(session_date) RANGE BETWEEN 8 preceding and 1 preceding )
),
tbl2 as ( -- check if the last 7 days entry happend. If not, then then increase main_session
  SELECT *, 
  countif(temp1=0) over win2 as main_session,
  from tbl1
  window win2 as (partition by  user  ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(session_date) RANGE BETWEEN unbounded preceding and CURRENT ROW  )
),
tbl3 as ( -- for each main_session get the starting date
SELECT *,
min(session_date) over win3 as main_session_date_start
from tbl2
window win3 as (partition by user,main_session)

),
tbl4 as ( -- count the day between starting date and the event
SELECT
    *,
    date_diff(session_date,main_session_date_start,day) as diff,
FROM tbl3)
,
tbl5 as ( -- divide by 7 days and round down. temp4 is the id the of session
  SELECT *,
  div(diff, 7) as temp3,
  main_session ||'-'||  div(diff, 7) as temp4
  from tbl4
),
tbl6 as ( -- get the last entry
  SELECT *, lag(temp4) over win2 as temp5 from tbl5
   window win2 as (partition by  user  ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(session_date))
),
tbl7 as ( -- if the temp4 is changing, then a new session started
  SELECT *, countif(ifnull(temp5!=temp4,true)) over win2 as session_counter
  from tbl6
  window win2 as (partition by  user  ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(session_date) RANGE BETWEEN unbounded preceding and CURRENT ROW  )
)


#SELECT * from tbl7

SELECT 
date_Add(main_session_date_start, interval 7*temp3 day)as session_start_end,
date_Add(main_session_date_start, interval 7*(1+temp3) day)as session_date_end,
*
from tbl7

